# Custom aspx page with web part

Tags: web-part, asp.net, aspx

What would be the best way to have a custom asp.net page which runs on sharepoint and displays a web part? TIA

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Would this page be inside or outside of sharepoint? And how custom do you want the aspx page? do you want a ribbon or?

Please elaborate. Maybe the answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49472/code-behind-aspx-pages-in-sharepoint-sandbox-solution will give you the answer you are looking for, as basically that is all this solution does. A custom aspx page with a webpart, this is to simulate a code behind page in a sandbox, but does what you are asking.

Comment: The page needs to be wiyh in shsrepoint and look/feel just like any other page, thanks for the link I'll have a look at it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Just had a chance to check the link and it worked great, cheers :)